# Which set is this with a white truck and camper trailer?

Tags: set-identification

I’ve been searching online for quite some time to find this set number, name, and the instructions, but I’ve had no luck. I’ll be passing it on to a youngster in the family and after it’s promptly destroyed I was hoping to have the instructions for him. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE!

Answer (score 7):

I believe this is the set:

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=6345-1

I searched on the vehicle roof piece, only 48 sets have it in white...

The instructions for this part of the set are pages 3 through 9 and are available on [Peeron](http://peeron.com/scans/6345-1/3/).

[image: truck instructions]

Comment: Thanks so much! That’s definitely it. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4):

[image]

**Set Number:** *6345*.

**Name:** *Aerial Acrobats*.

**Instructions:** We have at least ***3 options***: Two options are for free digital. One option is a physical purchase.

- **Option 1**. *[Here](http://lego.brickinstructions.com/lego_instructions/set/6345/Aerial_Acrobats)* are free online digital instructions for this
  set.

[image]

- **Option 2**. Skip over to *YouTube* and *[watch a speed build of this
  set](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xSBeMjoi-oc)*. In settings, (gear icon), you can slow the playback speed
  of the video and easily glean an understanding of the build.

[image]

- **Option 3**. It is possible to download and keep *YT* videos, but...if you
  still want to keep things traditional by wanting a physical hard copy
  for said youngster's future inheritance, then head on over to
  *Bricklink*, where for *[under $10 bucks](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?I=6345-1&name=Aerial%20Acrobats&category=%5BTown%5D%5BClassic%20Town%5D%5BAirport%5D#T=S&O=%7B%22loc%22:%22US%22,%22iconly%22:0%7D)*, you should be able to purchase the actual instruction booklet for this set.

[image]